# How to understand range in statement modifier in Perl?

Tags: perl

Perl supports range in statement modifier as below, how does the interpreter handle it together with `$.`? I am wondering the rule interpreter handles it since this is not a simple boolean expression.

```
while (<>)
{
  print if 10 .. 20;
  print if /pat1/ .. /pat2/;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used in scalar context, it's called the flip-flop operator.

---

When its operands are constants, they are compared to `$.`, so

```
print if 10 .. 20;
```

is short for

```
print if $. == 10 .. $. == 20;
```

The flip-flop will return true starting with line 10, until line 20.

```
$ perl -E'say for "a".."z"' |
   perl -ne'print if 10 .. 20;'
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
```

---

The rest of the time, the operands are evaluated as-is, so

```
print if /pat1/ .. /pat2/;
```

will return true starting with a line (`$_`) matching `pat1`, until a line (`$_`) matching `pat2`.

```
$ perl -E'say for "z", "xpat1x", "x", "xpat2x", "z", "ypat1y", "y", "ypat2y", "z"' |
   perl -ne'print if /pat1/ .. /pat2/;'
xpat1x
x
xpat2x
ypat1y
y
ypat2y
```

Comment: So this flip-flop operator stores the evaluation result of each iteration internally, so it can make decision based on previous iteration?

Comment: Yes, the count of how many times the LHS has matched in succession is stored in the instance of the flip-flop op. It uses that to dtermine which check it should perform.